# A resource failed to call close

Tags: properties, load, warnings

I'm getting the android logcat message "A resource failed to call close".  I've tracked it down to where that message gets generated.  Here's the code:

```
    Properties defaultProperties = new Properties();
    URL propURL = Util.class.getClassLoader().getResource(DEFAULT_PROPERTIES_FILE);
    if (propURL != null)
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        try
        {
            // Load properties from URL.
            is = propURL.openConnection().getInputStream();
            defaultProperties.load(is);
            is.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
```

The message is generated on the call to "defaultProperties.load(is)".

I put a breakpoint on that line, and when I step over that line, the warning message is generated.  I'm not the author of the code but that line gets executed at least two times and its the second time when that line gets called when the warning gets generated.  I just don't see how under any circumstances that a resource failed to close would be generated on that line. I'm at a lost to explain how or why that error message would be generated there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about this, I've come to the conclusion that the problem doesn't have anything to do with the line "defaultProperties.load(is)" causing the warning.  Although the message is always generated the second time that line is called, my current thought is that the problem is happening elsewhere but when this line gets called it's probably yielding to some other VM related thread time to process, and that process is detecting that some resource failed to close. I'm concluding that the problem is related to something altogether different and calling that line is the time when the problem surfaces, but it's not what's causing the problem.

Comment: Since this posting, I've learned how to track down the resource not closed issue:          try {
            // see https://wh0.github.io/2020/08/12/closeguard.html for an explanation
            Class.forName("dalvik.system.CloseGuard")
                    .getMethod("setEnabled", boolean.class)
                    .invoke(null, true);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

Comment: Where should the code mentioned in the article be added?

Comment: I added the code to my main Activity class (ie. AppCompatActivity)  in the onCreate method.  I think you can add it anywhere you want.  I'm not sure what happens if you add it after you already opened a file.  My guess is that files you already have opened when you call this code would not report the resource not being closed if you failed to close them, but again I'm not sure it that's the case or not. I simply put that code early enough in the execution so that I didn't need to know if that's the case or not.

Comment: I also think there's some overhead for having Dalvik use the CloseGuard feature. I think you would want to avoid calling that code in production code. If there wasn't any overhead, I don't think it would be implemented as a feature that you need to turn on or off.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find the reason why this is happening? My app prints the message (with "close" and/or "release") every time I start it in the emulator, always just before `onCreate` (first activity) is called, between `onCreate` and `onCreateView` (first fragment) or right at the start of `onCreateView`. I recently added code to download files from a server with `HttpURLConnection`, `InputStream` and `FileOutputStream` (I close all 3, of course) and that also seems to trigger it randomly but doesn't happen every time.

Comment: Yes I did, but your problem sounds different.  Activities and Fragments have slightly different Android lifecycles.  I'm not sure, but you may need to enable the CloseGuard feature for each Fragment.  If that's the case, then try putting the code to enable CloseGaurd in each Fragments onAttach method.